# Total derivative of $e^{xy}(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \longmapsto e^{xy}\cdot (x^2+y^2)$

Show for which $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}$ the function is totally differentiable. A function is totally differentiable if

a) $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-A\cdot h}{\Vert h \Vert}$

or

b) f is continuously partially differentiable

I first calculated the partial derivatives for both x and y:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=e^{xy}\cdot(yx^2+y^3+2x)$$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=e^{xy}\cdot(xy^2+x^3+2y)$$

Thus the jacobian Matrix is $\begin{array}{rrr} 
e^{xy}\cdot(yx^2+y^3+2x) & e^{xy}\cdot(xy^2+x^3+2y) \\
\end{array}$

The partial derivatives are continuous as they are a product of two continuous functions. Therefore according to b) f is totally differentiable $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Is this correct or did I make a mistake somewhere and f actually isn't totally differentiable for every point? Should this rather be done via a) or is that unnecessearily complex?

Comment: AFAICT, your partial derivatives are correct.

Comment: This is correct. You can also notice that $f$ is a product of two totally differentiable maps. hence is totally differentiable. Providing you know this result.